# Passing context on an html with both POST and GET options

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a html page with various submit buttons:

```
<h3>Add Address</h3>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        ...
        <input type="submit" value="Add" name="_add_add">
    </form>
<h3> Update values </h3>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        ...
        <input type="submit" value="Add" name="_update">
    </form>
<h3>Address</h3>
    <form method="get">
        ...display...
```

My view.py is:

```
def property(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if '_update' in request.POST:
            ...update values...
        elif '_add_add' in request.POST:
            ...add addres....
            Context = {"name_for_template":"value"}
    else:
        ... graph default values...
        Context = {"name_for_template":"value"}

    return render(request, 'address.html', context)
```

When there isn't a POST and simply a GET (like being redirected to the page), I get an CSRF error in the context (and it asked me to use request_context).  Is it possible (and how) to automatically send a default context for the GET, and send a different context for POST without incurring the CSRF error?

Comment: the function must return : context={}. return render(request, 'address.html', context).   And after, when you have post request, add value on context. Context = {"name_for_template":"value"}

Comment: I updated the question. I do define what context is.  The question is more about the CSRF error I get when context is sent via a GET. The page works fine when I send the context via a POST.

Comment: the 3th argument in render function must the context you want to send to the template, 
`def property(request):

    context = {}

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if '_update' in request.POST:

            ...update values...
        elif '_add_add' in request.POST:
            ...add addres....
            context["name_for_template"]= "value"
    else:
        ... graph default values...
        context["name_for_template"]= "value"

    return render(request, 'address.html', context)`

if it doesn't work, post your entire code.

Comment: See render() doc for function signatuture: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#render

Answer (score 0):

you can try this edit code

```
def property(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if '_update' in request.POST:
            ...update values...
        elif '_add_add' in request.POST:
            ...add addres....
            context["name_for_template"]= "value"
    else:
        ... graph default values...
        context["name_for_template"]= "value"
return render(request, 'address.html', context)
```

if it doesn't work, share your code

Comment: I see. It's an error on my part to use {} in the render function. I have updated it.  But I think the CSRF error still exists.  What I am trying to do is use the POST to modify the context values. In the absence of a POST, the GET should send a set of default context values.  The error is this: UserWarning: A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.
  "A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context "  Is this a problem with {% csrf_token %} in the html?

Comment: Yeah, i got the same error when using four arguments as you did above on your code, but when i use render with this 3 arguments (request, template_name, context). It works, no error anymore